# How do I get rid of NaTType does not support strftime error in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, lambda, apply

I have some empty rows in my 'Date' column. So when I try to use the code below to format my column, I get the error message

> "NaTType does not support strftime"

How do I avoid this error?

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `apply` in the first place. Use the `dt` accessor. It's more efficient and reliable in this case. Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2022-11-11", "not-a-time"]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors="coerce")

df["Date_string"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

# df
#         Date Date_string
# 0 2022-11-11  2022/11/11
# 1        NaT         NaN
```

Now you could also fill the NaN's with appropriate strings:

```py
df["Date_string"] = df["Date_string"].fillna("invalid_date")

# df
#         Date   Date_string
# 0 2022-11-11    2022/11/11
# 1        NaT  invalid_date
```